# Cassandra C# driver manual paging not working

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax

I am trying to use manual paging in Cassandra using C#.

Below are the version details:

It is the driver version 3.11.0

My server version is [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.4 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]

Below is the code which I am trying

```
 var cluster = Cluster.Builder()
 .AddContactPoints("x.x.x.x", "x.x.x.x", "x.x.x.x")
 .WithCompression(CompressionType.Snappy)
 .Build();
 var session = cluster.Connect("shekhar");

var statement = new SimpleStatement("select * from table ALLOW FILTERING");
statement.SetAutoPage(false);
statement.SetPageSize(1000);
var rs = await session.ExecuteAsync(statement);
int rowNo = 0;
foreach (var row in rs)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: Cooment has Id {1}, has tweet {2}", rowNo++, row.GetValue<BigInteger>("id"), row.GetValue<string>("xxx"));
//rs.FetchMoreResults();
//Console.WriteLine(rs.IsExhausted());
//Console.WriteLine(rs.IsFullyFetched);
//Console.WriteLine(rs.PagingState);
```

By setting **statement.SetAutoPage(false);** it fetches only one page.
The values for last statement `Console.WriteLine(rs.IsFullyFetched);` and `Console.WriteLine(rs.IsFullyFetched);` is `true` so using them too is not making any difference.

I have also followed the suggest on https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.13/features/paging/  section manual paging there `PagingState` is used in next statement.
Using this it keeps the pulling old data again and again.

Here is my implementation for the same

```
 var statement = new SimpleStatement("select * from table ALLOW FILTERING");
 statement.SetAutoPage(false);
 statement.SetPageSize(1000);
 int rowNum = 0;
 await GetAllData_PagedData(session, statement, null, rowNum);
 Console.ReadLine();

static async Task GetAllData_PagedData(ISession session, IStatement statement, byte[] pagingState, int rowNum)
    {
        var statement2 = statement
                       .SetPagingState(pagingState);
        var rs2 = session.Execute(statement2);
        var pagingState1 = rs2.PagingState;
        foreach (var row in rs2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: Cooment has Id {1}, has tweet {2}", rowNum++, row.GetValue<BigInteger>("id"), row.GetValue<string>("column2"));
        }
        if (!rs2.IsFullyFetched)
            await GetAllData_PagedData(session, statement2, pagingState1, rowNum);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("All Data fetched...");

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `if (!rs2.IsFullyFetched)` with `if (pagingState1 != null)`.

With `AutoPage` disabled, the `IsFullyFetched` method always returns `true` because it's meant to be used with the automatic paging feature of `RowSet`.